# Is there a downside to using a tuple as the single parameter to a value class?

Tags: scala

Scala 2.10 added support for [value classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html).  One of the limitations of a value class is that it "must have only a primary constructor with exactly one public, val parameter whose type is not a value class."

Is there any downside to using a tuple for that single val parameter?

For example, I'd like to create a value type to represent a period of time with a start and an end.  Because I can't have two parameters, I could represent that range as `(Long, Long)`.

```
case class Period(timeRange: (Long, Long)) extends AnyVal {
  def start: Long = timeRange._1
  def end: Long = timeRange._2
  def contains(time: Long): Boolean = time >= start && time < end
}
```

Would I still get the memory allocation benefit of value classes using this approach?

Comment: After thinking about this a bit more, my guess is that the answer is that the downside is that my approach creates 3 objects in this case: a tuple and a boxing object for each long. If I had just created a regular case class instead only one object would've been created. I think the moral of this story is that Scala's value classes are not C#'s structs.

Comment: And in some cases value class has to be allocated anyway. So there may be 4 objects allocated for single instance of this class. If this was a regular case class, there would be only one object.

Comment: My above is actually slightly wrong in this case.  Scala's Tuple2 has specialized types that allow it to not box primitives.  That magic runs out when you got to higher dimension tuples.

Comment: According to the Scala 2.10.0 source code, `Tuple2` is specialized for only for `Int`, `Long` and `Double` (on both slots). The combinatorics of specialization are problematic. This specialization yields 10 distinct classes (in the sense of distinct .class files)! (3 x 3 plus 1 for the generic form).

Comment: @RandallSchulz It looks like 2.10.1 includes specializations for `Char` and `Boolean` too.  https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.1/src/library/scala/Tuple2.scala#L19

Comment: Oh, joy! 26 classes for `Tuple2`!! The never-ending world of engineering tradeoffs...

Comment: Doesn't it seem a bit incongruous to use a tuple argument for your `Period` class? I like code optimisations when they are not too intrusive, but I would suggest that this one is distorting the code clarity somewhat.

Comment: @Rick-777 The whole point of the exercise was to get non-heap allocation.  I was willing to accept slight obfuscation for that benefit.  It all stemmed from mistaken belief that value classes were akin to C#'s structs and gave you value-type like behavior.  I was wrong.  Consequently, I think what I proposed is a Bad Idea(TM).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The downside is, as you've put it, that you will be creating an extra `Tuple2` object to store the two `Long`s. There will be no boxing, however -- `Tuple2` is specialized for `Long`.
So -- you are better off creating a case class in this case.

The following isn't directly related to your question, but may be useful. In some situations you need a typeclass if your value class is generic. For example, imagine that you want to add an additional factorial method `!` for `Numeric` types. You would have to do the following:

```
implicit class IntegralOps[T: Numeric](val x: T) extends AnyVal {
  def ! = ???
}
```

This won't work, because the typeclass constraint is translated into an additional implicit parameter and value classes only support one parameter:

```
implicit class IntegralOps[T](val x: T)(implicit $evidence: Numeric[T]) extends AnyVal {
  def ! = ???
}
```

The trick you can get away with in such cases is to move the typeclass parameter to all the extension methods:

```
implicit class IntegralOps[T](val x: T) extends AnyVal {
  def !(implicit $evidence: Numeric[T]) = ???
}
```

Since the same callsite is the same for the implicit conversion to the `IntegralOps` class and the call to the extension method, the same typeclass will apply in both cases.